# Is there any way to prevent an Elasticsearch field from being multivalued?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a field attribute in Elasticsearch, similar to Solr's multivalued (or any other way to achieve the same effect)? I need some fields to NOT be multivalued (examples: timestamp, language etc)? Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to prevent ES from indexing fields with multiple values. How are you indexing those documents? Is there any way you could enforce that constraint in your client code?

Comment: Sure I could do some checks in my code. But coming from Solr, this feels awkward and unnecessary...

Comment: I understand. Given to Lucene's nature, all fields are [multi-valued by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) and ES respects that. Solr used to behave exactly the same way in 1.0 but then in 1.1 the `multiValued` property was introduced and they made it false by default. I'm not aware of any way to achieve the same thing in ES. If I ever figure out, I'll certainly report it here. However, I still think that this should be the responsibility of the client code to enforce that constraint. If you feed garbage to ES, it will spit out garbage, too.